# How to center the content of cells in a data grid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row, alignment

I set the min height of a datagrid that way:

```
<DataGrid MinRowHeight="40">
```

After feeding the datagrid with datas, the text in each cell is top and left aligned.
I could not find an easy way to center that text.

Any suggestions for doing that?

Comment: This may help: http://www.kudinov.ru/?p=133

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Final solution:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridContentCellCentering" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution if your grid use columns other than DataGridTextColumn. The TextBlock style solutions will add a line bellow the text if you have templated columns on the grid.
If anyone could please explain what this code is doing...

Answer (score 30):

The following code will center the contents of cells in DataGrid:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This works great when using the built in datagrid with text columns

Comment: Note that since you're not actually setting any `DataGridCell` specific properties, you can omit the `TargetType="DataGridCell"` attribute, and declare this as a general purpose style in your app.xaml.

Answer (score 9):

you can use styles. i add a sample for DataGridCheckBoxColumn, i hope it put you in the right direction.

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="is active" IsReadOnly="False">
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                 <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
             </Style>
      </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
      <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
             <Binding Path="ISACTIVE" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" Converter="{StaticResource MyBoolToIsActiveConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                                 NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnExceptions="True">
                        </Binding>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Finally a solution that can be set to a single column. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 9):

use ElementStyle

```
 <DataGridTextColumn ElementStyle="{StaticResource Centering}"/>

  <Style x:Key="Centering" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the DataGrid's Vertical and HorizontalContentAlignment to Center

```
<DataGrid VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

If that doesn't work, you can use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981250/datagrid-row-content-vertical-alignment). It uses a style that aligns the DataGrid cell contents

Comment: Careful not to use 'VerticalAlignment' since that centers the datagrid but not its cells (children).

Answer (score 5):

This style will set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` for all `DataGridCell`s without needing to be applied explicitly.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

I find this to be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your style tag like this.....

```
 <Style x:Key="CellTextCentre" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter> 
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

This below code display datagrid cell conent in center..

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <!--DISPLAY CONTENT IN MIDDLE-->
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />                        
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly longer version of [Arpit Shah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29326219/8455197).

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RightAligned" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource RightAligned}" 
                            Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            Header="Quantity" Width="60" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Category, Mode=OneWay}" 
                            Header="Category" Width="150" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a better approach to center the content vertically:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```