# Text alignment in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm programming by WPF. I need a way to make center content of cells, in DataGrid control. I use this code also:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="360" Width="498"
    FontFamily="2  Badr" FontSize="18" 
    AlternatingRowBackground="LightCoral" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
    Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072093/how-to-center-the-content-of-cells-in-a-data-grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text alignment in a WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720732/text-alignment-in-a-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You need set DataGridCell style

```
    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: (to Lai32290)This is not my answer. Your answer add a column to my DataSet and do not set center even one of my cell contents.

Comment: This answer looks correct to me - how do you expect to know if the cell content is properly aligned without adding at least one column?

Comment: (to Babak) Sorry, that code realy not worked, I have edited my code, please try again

Comment: (to Lai32290)Thanks for your answer but it does not work. My contents are RTL (Right To Left). Is it issue?

Comment: @Babak.Abad to Answer you RTL isn't the problem his code works like expected

Comment: I think we can be glad that with WPF not all elements are of type object and that we have to add each property via styles etc.

Comment: how to set that in the <Window.Resources> instead ?

Answer (score 31):

For those who need to format only one dynamic DataGrid column in VB.NET from a custom XAML style:

In Application.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellCentered" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In VB.NET code:

```
Me.MyDataGrid.Columns(5).CellStyle = TryFindResource("DataGridCellCentered")
```

Regards!

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in other answers:

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

[image: HorizontalAlignment]

This will affect any other styles such as background. To only center the text use this instead:

```
<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

[image: textalign]

Answer (score 10):

Maybe just create a style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Edited.

Comment: How use this in my code? please explain more. I am new in xaml

Comment: You can add the style in the resource of your window

Comment: Not nice for me because then your textbox border/size maybe is not filling the cell size completely. So I prefer the answer from Lai32290

Comment: @Nelly a bit late, but this answer is much more effective than accepted answer if you need to do it on all your Grid cells. In my case I used that answer, and just added a style also on TextBlock, with also some margins to have a small space between TextBlock and Cell's borders

Answer (score 3):

for affect all column

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: It looks like this affects only Column Header.
Also : <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> is not required (is the default)
Do i miss something ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case this (very simple) is working fine:

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="MyDataGrid"
    ...
    TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center">
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to center the dates in a DataGridTemplateColumn

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="DataDiNascita" Header="Data di nascita" IsReadOnly="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DataDiNascita,Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                                
                        </DatePicker>                           
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataDiNascita,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                              
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

How to center text in WPF DataGrid

```
<DataGrid >
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Label.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depends on panel who is filled or docked in datagrid horizontal content alignment doesn't work
for center content alignment you can use DataGrid.resource tag like this

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

or see this one

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DgvUsers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                      IsTextSearchEnabled="True" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectionMode="Single" FontFamily="/Sandogh.App;component/Font/#Lalezar" >
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding Path=UserID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=Family}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Path=TGender}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="UserName" Binding="{Binding Path=UserName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Path=Password}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Activity" Binding="{Binding Path=TActivity}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="JobID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding Path=JobID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="JobName" Binding="{Binding Path=JobName}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```