# How to change the HorizontalAlignment of a DataColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid, datacolumn

I'm currently working on a dynamic `DataGrid` in WPF, so I create a `DataTable` directly in the ViewModel, and I bind it to my view :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable.DefaultView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

But I don't know how to change the **properties** like `HorizontalAlignment` in the C# code. I would like to set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center` for my `Column1`.

I've this code to create the `DataTable` :

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1"));
```

And this one to add rows :

```
DataRow row = datatable.NewRow();
row["Column1"] = myvalue;
datatable.Rows.Add(row);
```

Do I have to set **properties** in the XAML or in the C#, and how do I do?

Comment: You should read about styling in WPF. You can define a `Style` for your columns in XAML.

Comment: You may take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177153/text-alignment-in-datagrid