# How to vertically center rows' contents in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, coding-style, datagrid, vertical-alignment

I want to make the data record's  `VerticalAlignment=Center` in DataGrid. By default,the data record's  `VerticalAlignment=Top`, It looks uglily. Can you provide me this style?

I define my style in App.xaml file. The following is my current DataGrid style:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridView" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="AliceBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Horizontal"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="32"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `VerticalContentAlignment="Center"` on the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
  ...
</DataGrid>
```

or you can add a setter to your style:

```
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
```

When applied to `ItemsControl`s, this property usually modifies alignment of each individual item container. In your case, this should make all rows align their contents to center.

**UPDATE**

Seems like the WPF built-in `DataGrid` doesn't follow the rule.

The solution depends on the type of the columns you use.

For `DataGridTemplateColumn` use a `CellTemplate` like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!--Substitute the TextBlock by the actual cell content, but don't drop VerticalAlignment-->
  <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

For `DataGridTextColumn`, set `ElementStyle`:

```
<Style>
  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
```

I've tried this on `DataGridTextColumn`, but the property is from its parent `DataGridBoundColumn`, so should work for `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` and `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` also.

**Update 2**

BTW, [there's another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995839/795861).

Comment: Hi Pavel Gatilov,I try to add the VerticalContentAlignment="Center" in my style setters list, but it seems no effect.

Comment: By the way,the columns in DataGrid were created by my csharp code,not autogenerated by control itself. Because my ItemsSource is DataView and I can't know the columns which I want to display(They're come from database and the columns are dynamic).

Comment: @qingxu Please, see my updated post. I've tried those two options myself and they do work. The only thing is you probably won't be able to include this into the `DataGrid`'s `Style`, but you should be able to assign the properties when you create your columns.

Comment: thanks for your solution,I follow your suggestion and create the DataGridTemplateColumn instead of DataGridTextColumn,it works.As you said,the VerticalContentAlignment can work on DataGridTemplateColumn,DataGridCheckboxColumn and others except DataGridTextColumn.