# DataGridTextColumn is highlighted only on textblock when selected after defining an alignemnt

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, alignment, datagridtextcolumn

I have a datagrid which I define the styles and columns in code behind as following :

```
My_Data_Grid.ItemsSource = an_observableCollection ;
Style my_Style = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
DataGridTextColumn a_Column = new DataGridTextColumn();
a_Column.Header = "_Header_";
a_Column.Binding = new Binding("index");
a_Column.Width = 80;
a_Column.CellStyle = my_Style;
My_Data_Grid.Columns.Add(a_Column);
```

This snippet code will have a result like the following screenshot :

[image]

I want to change the alignment, so that I apply the following changes to previous code :

```
my_Style.Setters.Add(
            new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center));
my_Style.Setters.Add(
            new Setter(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
```

The effect will be the following screenshot :

[image]

As you notice, the alignment is fine now; but the selection is not the whole cell any more ! only the text is highlighted as selected !

Doest any one has any ideas how I can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that a TextBlock has no built-in support for vertical content alignment. To align the content inside your cells, you would have to overwrite the CellTemplate for the corresponding columns and set the vertical alignment on a wrapping grid or border.
Add this code to a resource dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="CenteredCellStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Use as

```
My_Data_Grid.ItemsSource = an_observableCollection ;
Style my_Style = Application.Current.FindResource("CenteredCellStyle") as Style;
DataGridTextColumn a_Column = new DataGridTextColumn();
a_Column.Header = "_Header_";
a_Column.Binding = new Binding("index");
a_Column.Width = 80;
a_Column.CellStyle = my_Style;
My_Data_Grid.Columns.Add(a_Column);
```

See: [DataGrid row content vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981250/datagrid-row-content-vertical-alignment)

Comment: Right, it won't work as I suggested earlier. I just updated my answer.