# C# wpf Datagrid content alignment center via code

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I generate a Datagrid and want to center the content.

this is my code:

```
DataGrid tabelle = new DataGrid();
tabelle.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
tabelle.RowHeight = 50;
tabelle.VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
tabelle.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
```

It doesnt work... but why?

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't work'? What do you see instead?

Comment: the content is not centered. I get the same result if I delete the last two lines

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it through code? in XAML, you have more easy to apply options ex. Style. Also, I assume u are using MVVM or MVC since you have ViewModel defined

Comment: im new to wpf. i dont know how to generate something dynamically via xaml, so i did it via code. And i think it should work, but not the way i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridCell template does not use VerticalContentAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment properties of DataGrid.

There are ways to get desired alignment. Take a look here: [DataGrid row content vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981250/datagrid-row-content-vertical-alignment)

here is a solution in code

```
DataGrid tabelle = new DataGrid();
tabelle.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
tabelle.RowHeight = 50;

// cell style with centered text
var cellStyle = new Style
                {
                    TargetType = typeof (TextBlock),
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center),
                        new Setter(TextBlock.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center),
                    }
                };

// assign new style for text columns when they are created
tabelle.AutoGeneratingColumn += (sender, e) =>
{
    var c = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (c != null)
        c.ElementStyle = cellStyle;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell)) { Setters = { new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center) } };

tabelle.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For autogenerated Columns, there is the AutoGeneratingColumn event that fires for every Column that gets autogenerated, and AutoGeneratedColumns that fires after all Columns are generated.

```
Private Sub dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns
          ' This event gets fired after all Columns have been autogenerated.
          Dim dataGrid As DataGrid = CType(sender, DataGrid)
          Dim cellStyle As Style
    
          For intI As Integer = 0 To dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1
             cellStyle = New Style With {
                        .TargetType = GetType(DataGridCell)
                    }
             cellStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center))
             dataGrid.Columns(intI).CellStyle = cellStyle
          Next
    End Sub
```

The other answers to this question needed slightly different Types to work for me or didnt include the event handling.